# htaccess rules causing 404 error

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have some rules in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vn/ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/news-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/(.+)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/vn/news-$2-$3/$4 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/product-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/vn/product-$2-$3/$4 [R=301,L]
```

But it seems that 2 rules above are conflicted. 
The 1st rule redirects successful, but the 2nd one causes the 404 error.

For example, when user access the URL : `https://mydomain/abc/news-0-1/article.html`, he will be redirected to `https://mydomain/vn/news-0-1/article.html` -> That's what I want.

But when he access the other URL like : `https://mydomain/abc/product-0-1/product.html`, it's a 404 error.

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help so much!

Comment: RewriteCond only applies to the next following RewriteRule.

Comment: what is the redirected URL for `https://mydomain/abc/product-0-1/product.html`?

Comment: @Ben: it's : https://mydomain/vn/product-0-1/product.html

Comment: properly you don't have the file inside the folder?

Comment: @Ben Never mind, I figured it out. Anyway, thanks for your time.